# Inner flexbox 100% height of parent div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is my slim and sass code. I need to make height of flex-container or flex-item to be 100% of parent div(flex-primary-content), You can look how it looks now in codepen: http://codepen.io/gmrash/pen/MazyaP (demanded div bordered dotted red)

```
div class='flex-primary-container'
  div class='flex-primary-header'
    |Header
  div class='flex-primary-content'
    div class='flex-container'
      div class='flex-item'
        |flex-inner-item


.flex-primary-container
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  border: 3px solid black
  height: 100vh
  .flex-primary-header
    flex-grow: 0
    flex-basis: 50px
  .flex-primary-content
    flex-grow: 1
    border: 2px solid blue
    .flex-container
      display: flex
      align-items: stretch
      border: 3px dotted red
    .flex-item
      flex-grow: 1
      overflow: hidden
```

Comment: `height: 100%` to `flex-container` does that: http://codepen.io/Manojkr/pen/BovYGm

Comment: nothing change I need dotted red div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the `flex-primary-content` be a flexbox container. Since `flex-container` acts as a child of flexible parent `flex-primary-content`, setting `flex-grow: 1` will occupy full height/width depending on the flex-direction.

**Code snippet(CSS version)**:

```css
.flex-primary-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 100vh;
}
.flex-primary-container .flex-primary-header {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-basis: 50px;
}
.flex-primary-container .flex-primary-content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: flex;
}
.flex-primary-container .flex-primary-content .flex-container {
  align-items: stretch;
  border: 3px dotted red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.flex-primary-container .flex-primary-content .flex-item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-primary-container">
  <div class="flex-primary-header">Header</div>
  <div class="flex-primary-content">
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="flex-item">flex-inner-item</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo - SASS version**](http://codepen.io/Manojkr/pen/wKRyRy)